# Ruby on Rails: How to order by intermediate model's field?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a common models in relations like this:

user.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :likes
```

diary.rb

```
class Diary < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :likes
  has_many :liked_users, through: :likes, source: :user
```

like.rb

```
class Like < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :diary
```

And now, I wanna order

```
@diary.liked_users
```

by `likes.created_at` .

What way is the most simplest, and fastest in performance ?

Answer (score 2):

### Short answer

`@diary.liked_users.order('likes.created_at ASC')`

### Why does this work?

So internally rails issues a query that looks like this:

```
Select users.* FROM like INNER JOIN users ON users.id = like.user_id WHERE like.diary_id = 1
```

1 here is just an example of the id of the diary you are applying this method on.

This means that `likes` table is already present in the query

Therefore `@diary.liked_users.order('likes.created_at ASC')` would generate something like this:

```
Select users.* FROM likes INNER JOIN users ON users.id = likes.user_id WHERE likes.diary_id = 1 ORDER BY likes.created_at ASC
```